# how to install pecl mail parse on mamp?

Tags: php, mamp, php-extension, pecl

I use MAMP 2.0.5 , php5.3.6 , OS X 10.7.2

I would like to install pecl extension (mail parse)

but I'm stuck with this error
Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 276 of 1133 bytes in Config.php on line 1050
ERROR: The default config file is not a valid config file or is corrupted.

anyone ?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error after using the pear/pecl binaries from the MAMP installation.

You better edit the file

> /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.3.6/conf/pear.conf

as described [in the MAMP forums here](http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?t=13815#p29192), just search for "php_dir" and decrease the number that is following by 1. Alternatively you can rename/delete the file like in [this tutorial](http://www.lullabot.com/articles/installing-php-pear-and-pecl-extensions-on-mamp-mac-os-x-107-lion#comment-9548), but I recommend to edit it.